# Placeholder as "dd/mm/yyyy? on date input in phonegap not working on phone

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, date

I am using phonegap/cordova to make mobile app, I have an form where there is an input type="date" for picking date. I have used placeholder for setting text on the input type="date" which works perfectly on browser (desktop), but when I am viewing the same form on phone it doesn't works i.e. it shows blank instead of placeholder text.

Please help me how to display the placeholder of input type="date" in phone (android).

I have tried all the possible solutions, setting it as type="text" and making it as type="date" on focus and other stuffs. Please help

Thanks.
Krunal

Answer (score 0):

`input type="date"` is not a good practice as it is not supported in all browser. it might not work in old phone.

I advice you to use this plugin https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

after adding this plugin use following code in click/tap event of input tag

```
 var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date',
    androidTheme: 5
};

function onSuccess(date) {
    alert("Selected date is "+date);
}

function onError(error) {
    alert("you canceled the dialog.")
}

datePicker.show(options, onSuccess, onError);
```

have a look at plugin's `Readme.md` for more options.

you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to show date as your desired format.